# Split a variable definition in different lines

Tags: makefile

Ok, I suppose this one is silly (and have done it in the past) but I honestly cannot remember how it's done.

I have a variable like :

```
GCC = gcc
```

So, far so good...

Now, what if **my variable definition is too long** and want to split it into different lines, so that it looks nice and manageable?

```
D_FILES     = main console globals components/program components/statement components/statements components/assignment components/loop components/block components/library components/argument components/expression components/expressions components/functionDecl components/ruleDecl components/functionCall components/functionCallSt components/returnSt components/outSt components/inSt
```

Comment: Like this http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html#Multi_002dLine

Comment: Insert a backslash after putting whatever number of values you want, followed by newline, tab and then more values (backslash, newline, tab, values again...)

Comment: @devnull Tried that one (the first one I tried actually) but for whatever reason it seems to be breaking... :S

Comment: _For whatever reason it seems to be breaking_ is not a problem description that we can do anything with.  If it doesn't work, ask THAT question and provide an example (cut and paste, not paraphrased!) of what you did and exactly what error message you got.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this

```
CFLAGS = $(CDEBUG) -I. -I$(srcdir) $(DEFS) \
        -DDEF_AR_FILE=\"$(DEF_AR_FILE)\" \
        -DDEFBLOCKING=$(DEFBLOCKING)
```

put backslash at and and new line starting with `TAB`.

Comment: No need to start the lines with `TAB` (that will just embed `TAB`s inside the definition of _CFLAGS_). I recommend indenting with two spaces. The indenting shows the structure, and reserves `TAB`s for use in recipes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're having trouble using backslashs, but you can do it this way:

```
D_FILES = main console globals components/program components/statement
D_FILES += components/statements components/assignment components/loop
D_FILES += components/block components/library components/argument
# and so on
```